# Dart - How to receive and decode JSON packet sent from a Java application

Tags: java, json, sockets, socket.io, dart

In my server-side code I need to be able to listen to a socket to exchange JSON 'packets' with a Java 7 test application *on the same machine*.  The connection is made and a JSON string is constructed and written to the socket by the Java test application.  It is received by the Dart server-side application and passed to a callback method, handleJson, which attempts to decode it.  The process dies on 'JSON.decode'.

I think it dies because the string is prepended, by the Java 'writeUTF' method with a short int that contains the number of bytes in the JSON UTF-8 uncluding the leading short and the leading byte is 0.

1. Is there a Dart method to handle this, in each direction, or must I write the code? (I had thought that JSON work easily between languages.)

The JSON string before writing to the socket in my Java test application:

```
{"target":"DOOR","command":"OPEN"} // 34 characters
```

A Java snippet:

```
  // in a try-catch 
Socket client = new Socket(serverName, port);
OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);

out.writeUTF(json);

client.close();
```

The Java documentation states that the out.writeUTF method converts the json string to UTF-8 with the string length prepended as a short int containing the total number of bytes  written.

In main:

```
ServerSocket.bind('127.0.0.1', 4041)
   .then((serverSocket) {
  print('connected');
      // prints: 'connected'
   serverSocket.listen((socket) {
      socket.transform(UTF8.decoder).listen(handleJson);
   });
});
```

handleJson method:

```
handleJson(String stringAsJson){
  print('string length is ' + (stringAsJson.length).toString());
    // prints:  'string length is 36' 
  print('received json $stringAsJson');
    // prints: 'received json '
  String json = JSON.decode(stringAsJson);
    // dies on decode
  print('Sever Socket received: $json');
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you some troubles, since Socket is raw TCP, and TCP is streaming. That means that the text (bytes) you send can be split and merged in any way the network may find suitable.

In your case, you need a way to mark the end of each JSON message. An example could be to accumulate all bytes received, until the byte 0 is seen (invalid in JSON). Those bytes could then be converted to UTF8 and then again converted to JSON. Note that the peer needs to send this 0 byte in between messages, for this to work.

Now, you also consider using WebSockets as a way to sent messages. After the initial HTTP handshake, it's actually just a raw TCP socket with some extra header information, to make it package oriented - exactly what you need. `dart:io` already includes a WebSocket implementation.

Comment: Ultimately I want the Dart server-side code to listen to the client on a web socket (I can do that) *and* to listen on a 'regular' socket for data from a Java program running on the same computer using Gson.  This is to pass user requests generated when a button is clicked to the Java code for action.  Java code responses would travel the other way and I thought that JSON would be the right tool.  I do have a small Java test program to generate a JSON message using JohnYates code below but I get an error in the first line in his jsonprint that suggests the first char is bad.

Comment: I've restated the question after rewriting code and identifying the core problem.

Comment: I'm accepting this a an answer since it headed me in the right direction.  See [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22645809/dart-how-to-parse-bytes-from-a-string)