# Dart How to parse bytes from a String

Tags: java, json, string, sockets, dart

My server side Dart application receives a JSON String from a socket.  The string is generated by Java code.  When the string is sent to the socket in the Java code it is encoded to UTF8 and two bytes, a short int, are prepended to the string.  The value of this short is the number of bytes in the string + 2.

I need to extract that value as an int in order to handle the string but nothing I've tried has worked. It dies at JSON.decode (below) because it encounters the start of another JSON string.  The first byte of the second string is the start short with the length of the second JSON string. The two strings are each less then 40 characters long.

(I will need to append the length to strings sent from Dart to Java as well.)

Java line

```
out.writeUTF(json); // converts and writes to the socket stream.
```

Dart server side code method

```
handleJavaSocket(Socket javasocket){
   javasocket.transform(UTF8.decoder).listen((String socketString){
   var truncated = socketString.substring(2);
   String message = JSON.decode(truncated); // dies here
      // more code
   }, onError: (error) {
     print('Bad JavaSocket request');
   });

}
```

One of the JSON strings before encoding

```
{"target":"DOOR","command":"OPEN"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to convert the two byte header to an integer especially since one byte could be 0 and some string methods look at that as a string terminator.

Since a message from the Java application will always consist of the header followed by the message I ignore the header and parse the message(s) from the Stream adding them to a list (in order to echo them back as verification),

I then traverse the list and simulate the header by writing a 0 byte followed the message size to the stream stream followed by the message.  This won't work as is with message lengths greater than 255 but I don't expect any even close to that size.

it should be noted that the Dart application and the Java application are on the same machine.

```
handleJavaSocket(Socket javasocket){
  // echo socket
  javasocket.transform(UTF8.decoder).forEach((item) {
    var start = 2;
    var end = -1;
    var messages = new List<String>();
    while((++end < item.length) && (end = item.indexOf('}',end)) != -1) {
      messages.add(item.substring(start, ++end));
      start = end + 2;
    }
    for(var message in messages) {
      // header message length as two bytes
      javasocket.writeCharCode(0); // max length 254
      javasocket.writeCharCode(message.length); 
      javasocket.write(message); // <== send
    }
  });

}
```

Answer (score 2):

So you're always sending as [sizeuper8, sizelower8, ..utf8-string...] as your message boundaries? UTF8 decode doesn't expect length as a parameter and sees the two bytes as unicode (probably null followed by a character).

I'm currently working on a StreamBuffer for Quiver (https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/quiver) that will let you pipe the socket to a buffer that gives you:

`read(2).then((bytes) => read(bytes[1]<<8|bytes[2]).then((string) => UTF8.decode(string)));`

You can can post the decoded string for whatever you like after that, but it should demux your data.

Current pull request (work in progress): https://github.com/google/quiver-dart/pull/117

Comment: That's what I thought and it worked ok when the Java code sent a string and Dart sent it back.  I then set the Java code up to send a second string, after some computation but it appears that the second string, (or god forbid - part of it) was appended to the first one.  Both the Java code and the Dart code will reside on the same machine and send strings asynchronously so I can't rule out that this concatenation won't occur in the final app.  I see that Dart supports UDP ...

Comment: I use UDP as well and that would make sense for your application, plus you get to drop the length encoding!